# Integrating Instagram to android

Tags: android, performance, instagram

I am new to instagram concept. Is there any sdk available for to integrating instagram to our application. I want to share images to instagram through my application as like what i share to facebook from my application.

Comment: I'm also having same thing to develop, can you share your experience about this topic?

Comment: No, we cant include the instagram to android app. there is no api to call instagram. pl verify the link given in below answer. but we have workaround for this. check this link http://www.kpbird.com/2013/01/android-instagram-integration.html.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you cannot post images to instagram from other applications.

Here’s some text from the very bottom of:
http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/

At this time, uploading via the API is not possible. We made a conscious choice not to add this for the following reasons:

Instagram is about your life on the go – we hope to encourage photos from within the app. However, in the future we may give whitelist access to individual apps on a case by case basis.
We want to fight spam & low quality photos. Once we allow uploading from other sources, it's harder to control what comes into the Instagram ecosystem. All this being said, we're working on ways to ensure users have a consistent and high-quality experience on our platform.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think there is a option to share images from iphone. But i cant able to get those sdk for android.

Comment: [This](http://instagram.com/developer/endpoints/media/) says uploading via the API is not possible.

Comment: Thank you so much. useful information. is this same applicable to ios ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific api to integrate instagram to Android application. But we can pass the intent in order to share the images if the device installed instagram.

Comment: so,Its not possible without using intent?because we can integrate instagram to our app,so there should be a tricky way to share photo too.